# Reading iOS Smart Card Reader Data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, encryption, smartcard

I'm developing an iOS application to read both Swipe and `NFC` smart card. I'm using `FEITIAN aR520` card reader (audioJack connection) to read the card data.

Here is what I get from their sample code:

```
encText:
988A348784312745703AF8D65B95B3EA
decText:
45521551105216585752521F57
currentKSN:
FFFF9876543210E00004
```

The decrypted text doesn't look like a card number or something!!

Comment: What kind of object is the dectText? Is a NSData?

Comment: unsigned char decData[1024] = {0};

Comment: It looks to me, that KSN is the unique card serial number, supplied by the chip manufacturer. The embossed card number is completely unrelated. While it is probably also stored electronically somewhere on the card, you need a card specification, to know where and how to get it.

Comment: how can you download the iOS SDK of FEITIAN aR520?

Comment: Do you have solution for it? I am stuck in this problem.

Comment: @JagveerSinghRajput: You would not be able to get the actual card data unless you know the data structure (maybe even encryption) of the card. You should contact the card manufacturer to get those information